# Extracting Text from a cell move it in to a cell on another worksheet

Tags: string, excel, vba, text, worksheet

Hello StackOver Flow folks,

I'm rather new to the VBA language and workflow, but I have some experience coding. My problem that the title does not really help to explain is this:

I receive emails daily that contain information I need to extract out of and move into their corresponding cells. Example of the email is as follows, which I have copied out of Outlook in to an excel worksheet I have named "RawData". I will label columns as **A)**

```
**A)** Send Date
01/01/2014 Timestamp
**B)** Subject
([Type]) word IndetifierOne IndetifierTwo word 100001
**C)** Body
Item HYPERLINK (www.thistheexample.com/100001) Subitem Name HYPERLINK (www.thistheexample.com/name/99321)keyword **All this Information is irrelevant** Item Names
HYPERLINK (www.thistheexample.com/name/99321)keyword HYPERLINK (www.thistheexample.com/name/99321)keyword HYPERLINK (www.thistheexample.com/name/99321)keyword
```

What needs to be extracted and placed within the columns in order is the

```
**A)** Date
**B)** Identifier Two 
**C)** This has other information input into it later manually 
**D)** Identifier One **E)** keyword sometimes has more than one line in it separated by a , will vary often 
**F)** Timestamp 
**G)** (www.thistheexample.com/100001) this one needs to be a HYPERLINK, the part before the "/" is always the same the IdValue "100001" will change 
**H)** IdValue from (www.thistheexample.com/100001) which would be 100001
```

To re-iterate on what I need help with is, I'm unsure of how to get all of this information sorted and placed in to the right cells on an different worksheet, I have been combing StackOverFlow, Mr.Excel for help and guidance but have hit a wall with the information. I'm looking for suggestions or something I can manipulate to do the job please and thank you. Have also tried many different ideas but none of them performed what I needed to a T, to make this task mostly automated.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Is a screen shot possible? Although your explanation is sound, coding will vary n how your data is organized. Also, you manually copy from OL to XL then automate?

Comment: I apologize but a screenshot is not possible due to legal reasons, no I automated the copying from Outlook to Excel just recently also with some troubles but I got it working. I tried to give as good a representation of the data as I could as each email is spread across 3 columns A, B, C on my RawData worksheet, the emails are processed in a descending order of newest to oldest. While the processed Data is spread across A, B, C, D, E, F, G, and H columns ascending oldest to newest. I will try to construct a clone without the actual data being processed, but with the same idea behind it.

Comment: I can not post images due to not having enough reputation. If there is a solution to this please let me know what it is. Thank you for our help and time folks

Comment: Hey all, its taken me a bit to get these images together due to my work taking up much of my time. Here are the links to the images.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Y9Ftbrj.jpg - this is the Raw Data

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/VLC85g4.jpg - this is the Processed Data

Answer (score 0):

I do not always understand your description because I can not decide if your explanation is part of the email or just there to show us what is it.

If the email's are coming in the same structure I would not use VBA. Just formulas:

To extract the date :In Sheet A1)

=MIDDLE(RawData!A1,SEARCH(" ",RawData!A1,1)+1,LENGTH(RawData!A1)-SEARCH(" ",RawData!A1,1))

This will extract from sheet RawData cell A1 everything after the space. If your date format is always the same (like "16/02/2014" - 10 characters) than to make sure nothing else is extracted you can try:
=MIDDLE(RawData!A1,SEARCH(" ",RawData!A1,1)+1,10)

If you want to use VBA:
The middle option is builded in:
Date = Mid(Cells(1,1), 5, 10)

The Search function can be called:
SpacePlace = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(" ", Cells(1,1), 10)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. It isn't quite what I was looking for as a solution to my problem

Comment: I will use it for future reference, I want VBA cause I need other tasks performed that I am looking in to to do.